# woocommerce wp_set_post_terms only works for admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm using wp_insert_post for adding a woocommerce product with taxonomy "product_cat". Here is my code.

First I add a new product.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title' => 'My Title',
            'post_content' => 'This is custom template',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => "product",
        ) );
```

and here, I attached terms with that post

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array(12,13), 'product_cat' );
```

But on shop page when I click on that specific category on which I add my product, the product is not display on that category, but on backend (wp admin) I see the terms are attached with my product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to update "_visibility"

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
```

Now, It's working fine.